# Oracle query to convert one row into two rows considering specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle SQL. I need a SQL query which could convert the table mentioned below. I have tried few options like unpivot, union, etc but still I couldn't able to achieve.

**I have a table like this:**

```
SNO     Name    Sales   Profit
1      John       50    20
2      Peter      60    NULL 
3      Mark       15    10
4      Nicolas   NULL  -10
5      Alex       70    20
```

**I need to get it as below**

```
SNO     Name    Sales   Profit  Sal/Pro
1      John     50      NULL    Sales
1      John     NULL    20      Profit
2      Peter    60      NULL    Sales
3      Mark     15      NULL    Sales
3      Mark     NULL    10      Profit
4      Nicolas  NULL    -10     Profit
5      Alex     70      NULL    Sales
5      Alex     NULL    20      Profit
```

Also, I'd appreciate if there is any other approach to handle this.

Comment: What's the source data? Can there be both Sales and Profit non-null in the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses `union all`:

```
select SNO, Name, Sales, NULL as Profit, 'Sales' as sales_pro
from t
where profit is not null
union all
select SNO, Name, NULL as Sales, Profit, 'Profit' as sales_pro
from t
where sales is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    SNO, Name, Sales, Profit,
    case
        when Sales is not null then 'Sales'
        when Profit is not null then 'Profit'
        else null
    end as sales_pro
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient approach (which reads the data from your base table only once) uses a cross-join to a small helper table you can create on the fly - as an inline view, in the FROM clause of your query.

Notice the WITH clause at the top - it is there only to allow me to test the query. It is not part of the solution; remove it, and use your actual table and column names.

```
with
  test_data ( sno, name, sales, profit ) as (
    select 1, 'John'   ,   50,   20 from dual union all
    select 2, 'Peter'  ,   60, NULL from dual union all 
    select 3, 'Mark'   ,   15,   10 from dual union all
    select 4, 'Nicolas', NULL,  -10 from dual union all
    select 5, 'Alex'   ,   70,   20 from dual
  )
select   sno, name, 
         case sal_pro when 'Sales'  then sales  end as sales,
         case sal_pro when 'Profit' then profit end as profit, sal_pro
from     test_data
         cross join
         (select 'Sales' as sal_pro from dual union all select 'Profit' from dual)
where    case sal_pro when 'Sales' then sales else profit end is not null
order by sno, sales
;

       SNO NAME         SALES     PROFIT SAL_PR
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ------
         1 John            50            Sales 
         1 John                       20 Profit
         2 Peter           60            Sales 
         3 Mark            15            Sales 
         3 Mark                       10 Profit
         4 Nicolas                   -10 Profit
         5 Alex            70            Sales 
         5 Alex                       20 Profit
```